# How to know each route position between two locations on Google map iOS sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios, xcode5.0.1

I am using [Google map iOS sdk](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start) for getting direction.By this [LINK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) help me to draw route between two points.Now i cannot give route instruction (e.g.: Turn Left,Turn right) to the end user. How to solve this issue?Please help me.Now i am using following code

```
//Request the url 
-(void)getWayPoints:(CLLocationCoordinate2D )origin destinationIS:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)desti{

NSString *oLat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",origin.latitude];
NSString *oLong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",origin.longitude];

NSString *dLat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",desti.latitude];
NSString *dLong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",desti.longitude];

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&origin=%@,%@&destination=%@,%@&sensor=false",oLat,oLong,dLat,dLong];
NSLog(@"url : %@", url);
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
                                                            origin.latitude,
                                                             origin.longitude);
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
marker.map = mapView_;

CLLocationCoordinate2D position1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
                                                             desti.latitude,
                                                             desti.longitude);
GMSMarker *marker1 = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position1];
marker1.map = mapView_;

NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
 NSLog(@"googleRequestURL : %@", googleRequestURL);

dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});



//Response from URL

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
//parse out the json data
NSError* error;
//  NSLog(@"responseData Data: %@", responseData);
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];
NSArray* places = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];

 NSDictionary *routes = [json objectForKey:@"routes"][0];

NSDictionary *route = [routes objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];

NSArray *routes1 = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];
NSArray *legs = [routes1[0] objectForKey:@"legs"];
NSLog(@"legs %@", legs);
NSArray *steps = [legs[0] objectForKey:@"steps"];

 NSString *overview_route = [route objectForKey:@"points"];
 GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:overview_route];
 GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
 polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
 polyline.strokeWidth = 5.f;
 polyline.map = mapView_;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=false",self.txtFrom.text,self.txtTo.text];
>
> NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
>
> NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
>
> NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
>
>
> NSError* error;
>
> NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
>
> NSArray* latestLoans = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];
>
> NSMutableDictionary *legs=[[[latestLoans objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"legs"] objectAtIndex:0];
>
> NSString *startLocation,*endLocation,*totalDistance,*totalDuration;
>
> CLLocationCoordinate2D startLoc,endLoc;
>
> startLocation = [legs  objectForKey:@"start_address"];
>
> endLocation = [legs objectForKey:@"end_address"];
>
> totalDistance = [[legs objectForKey:@"distance"] objectForKey:@"text"];
>
> totalDuration = [[legs objectForKey:@"duration"] objectForKey:@"text"];
>
> startLoc=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[legs objectForKey:@"start_location"] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[[legs objectForKey:@"start_location"] objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]);
>
> endLoc=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[legs objectForKey:@"end_location"] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[[legs objectForKey:@"end_location"] objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]);
>
>
> NSArray *steps=[legs objectForKey:@"steps"];
>
> NSMutableDictionary *tempDict;
>
> if ([steps count]!=0) {
>
>
>     MKMapPoint* pointArr = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * [steps count]+2);
>
>     [tv setText:@""];
>
>     for(int idx = 0; idx < [steps count]+2; idx++)
>     {
>
>         CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;
>
>         if (idx==0) {
>
>             workingCoordinate=startLoc;
>
>             MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(workingCoordinate);
>
>             pointArr[idx] = point;
>
>             [tv setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",tv.text,@"START"]];
>
>         }
>
>         else if (idx==[steps count]+1){
>
>             workingCoordinate=endLoc;
>
>             MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(workingCoordinate);
>
>             pointArr[idx+1] = point;
>
>             [tv setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",tv.text,@"\nEND"]];
>
>         }
>
>         else{
>
>             MKPolyline *pol= [self polylineWithEncodedString:[[[steps objectAtIndex:idx-1] objectForKey:@"polyline"] objectForKey:@"points"]];
>
>             MKMapPoint point = *(pol.points);
>
>             pointArr[idx] = point;
>
>             [tv setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n%@",tv.text,[self flattenHTML:[[steps objectAtIndex:idx-1] objectForKey:@"html_instructions"]]]];
>
>         }
>
>
>         tempDict = nil;
>     }
>
>     // create the polyline based on the array of points.
>     [mapView removeOverlay:routeLine];
>
>     routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointArr count:[steps count]];
>
>     [mapView addOverlay:routeLine];
>
>     free(pointArr);
> }
> ```

with following supporting methods:

> -(NSArray*) calculateRoutesFrom:(NSString *) f to: (NSString *) t {   NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@", f, t];
>
> NSURL* apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrlStr];
>   NSLog(@"api url: %@", apiUrl);
>   NSString *apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
>     @try {
>
> ```
>     // TODO: better parsing. Regular expression?
>
>     NSInteger a = [apiResponse indexOf:@"points:\"" from:0];
>     NSInteger b = [apiResponse indexOf:@"\",levels:\"" from:a] - 10;
>
>     NSInteger c = [apiResponse indexOf:@"tooltipHtml:\"" from:0];
>     NSInteger d = [apiResponse indexOf:@"(" from:c];
>     NSInteger e = [apiResponse indexOf:@")\"" from:d] - 2;
>
>     NSString* info = [[apiResponse substringFrom:d to:e] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\x26#160;" withString:@""];
>     NSLog(@"tooltip %@", info);
>
>     NSString* encodedPoints = [apiResponse substringFrom:a to:b];
>
>     return [self decodePolyLine:[encodedPoints mutableCopy]];
>
> }
> @catch (NSException * e) {
>     // TODO: show error
> }
> ```
>
> }